# Filter search attribute of tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image gallery with a search box. When I type in the search box I want the search to be made on the `data-title` attribute specifically *i.e.* "**A Great view of fields**" and *not* on the `alt` attribute. The code below works but it searches on the `innerHTML` of the tag and not the `data-title` attribute specifically, how do I make it search on the specific attribute only.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("gallery");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for caption" title="Type in a name">

<ul id="gallery">

  <li>
    <a href="image/photos/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="A Great view of fields"><img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Field"></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="image/photos/02.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="We are close to the land"><img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Sea"></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="image/photos/03.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Great field for grazing cows."><img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Green fields"></a>
  </li>
```

Comment: Did you check to see what's actually in the innerHTML? If so, please share.

Comment: Because the `data-title` attribute is on the `a` tag, not in the `innerHTML`, like the `alt` attribute is... If you want to search the attribute's value, get the attribute's value.

Comment: try using `querySelectorAll` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Thanks for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on a specific attribute by using the `.getAttribute()` function which returns the value of that attribute in this case you use `a.getAttribute("data-title").toUpperCase()`, then filter the results by that, example:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("gallery");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.getAttribute("data-title").toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
myFunction()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for caption" title="Type in a name" value="cow">

<ul id="gallery">

  <li>
    <a href="image/photos/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="A Great view of fields"><img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Field"></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="image/photos/02.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="We are close to the land"><img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Sea"></a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="image/photos/03.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Great field for grazing cows."><img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Green fields"></a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="image/photos/02.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="We are close to the land"><img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Sea"></a>
  </li>


  <li>
    <a href="image/photos/03.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Great field for grazing cows."><img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Green fields"></a>
  </li>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks your code worked to really appreciated guys thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

Because you hardcoded in the HTML source the **onkeyup** event, I'd suggest you to add the following two parameters:

- this: current element
- event: the event object

Change from:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for caption" title="Type in a name">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this, event)" placeholder="Search for caption" title="Type in a name">
```

In this way your function will receive the two arguments and you can take advantage o those:

```js
function myFunction(ele, evt) {
    //
    // get current input value
    //
    var filter = ele.value.toUpperCase();
    //
    // for each anchor under an li belongint to gallery....
    //
    document.querySelectorAll("#gallery li a").forEach(function(ele, idx) {
        //
        // get the title data attribute
        //
        var title = ele.dataset.title.toUpperCase();
        //
        // set the display style
        //
        ele.parentNode.style.display = (title.indexOf(filter) == -1) ? "none" : "";
    })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction(this, event)" placeholder="Search for caption" title="Type in a name">
<ul id="gallery">
    <li>
        <a href="image/photos/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="A Great view of fields">
            <img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Field"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="image/photos/02.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="We are close to the land">
            <img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/02.jpg" alt="Sea"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="image/photos/03.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Great field for grazing cows.">
            <img class="thumb" src="image/photos/thumbnails/03.jpg" alt="Green fields"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the code worked fantastic I really appreciated